# Unknown column in JOIN ON statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT * FROM `a` LEFT JOIN  `dates` ON `a.date_id`=`dates.id` AND `dates.date`>'19-09-2013'
```

The above query gets `#1054 - Unknown column 'a.date_id' in 'on clause'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you escape a table or column name you have to do it seperatly

```
SELECT * FROM a 
LEFT JOIN  `dates` ON a.date_id = `dates`.`id` AND `dates`.`date` > '19-09-2013'
```

Use

```
`dates`.`id`
```

instead of

```
`dates.id`
```

But you actually only have to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).